# Swift expression type is ambigious without more context

Tags: ios, swift

Please consider following code:

```
 func checkIfNewVersionAvailable() -> (isNewAvailable : Bool, error : String?){

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            do {
                let update = try self.isUpdateAvailable()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    return (true, nil)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return (false, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

On line :  return (true, nil) compiler throw me an error : `Expression type '(_, _)' is ambiguous without more context`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use the result of an asynchronous task as a return value of a function. That's impossible. And the parameter labels are useless in Swift 3+

Comment: You cannot *return on the main queue*, that does not make any sense, how would a call of this method logically happen?

Comment: @luk2302 thank you

Comment: @vadian thanks. What you mean - parameter labels are useless in Swift 3? You mean in tuples?

Comment: I mean omit the parameter labels in closures and return values like `-> (Bool, String?)` or `completion : (Bool, String?) -> ()`

Comment: @vadian ok, clear now for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is

```
func checkIfNewVersionAvailable(@escaping completion : ((isNewAvailable : Bool, error : String?) -> ())) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            do {
                let update = try self.isUpdateAvailable()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(true,nil)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(false,error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now issue :

DispatchQueue.main.async does not expects any return value and you are trying to return a tuple of type (bool,String) hence its mentioning the issue

> thanks but i dont want to add closure, i want to return tuple.

You are executing  `self.isUpdateAvailable` asynchronously on a global queue with default priority. So the call to `self.isUpdateAvailable` is not synchronous where as your return statements are synchronous ones hence even if you manage to write return statement somehow you won't have proper values while returning because `self.isUpdateAvailable` might still be running or waiting to run when your return gets executed.

Comment: thanks but i dont want to add closure, i want to return tuple.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban yes, you *want* / *have to* use a closure.